# I want to check if the child exist (which is userid) or not but i am facing logical error

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i  am trying to make an app where user can give his/her emergency phone number(others) and emeregency message ... SO i am saving the data in firebase realtime database and if the user already given the phone then he/she should dirctly intent to second page.. SO here i am doing a check if the phone_number exist or not but logical error is there

MAINACITVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.loginapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String uniqueID = UUID. randomUUID(). toString();
    public static String phone_number;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Emergency_message");
    private static final int ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 123 ;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this ,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);


        checkexist();




        } // onCreate

    private void checkexist() {
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Emergency_message");
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(phone_number)) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , second.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            System.out.println(uniqueID);
                        }



                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
         


    }


    public void smsbutton(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
         phone_number = editText.getText().toString();
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName4);
        String value2 = editText2.getText().toString();
        dataholder obj = new dataholder(phone_number, value2);








        myRef.child(uniqueID).setValue(obj);
       openAcitivity(phone_number, value2);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data send ",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    public void openAcitivity(String value , String value2){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , second.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**SECOND ACITIVITY (NOT SO IMPORTANT)**

```
package com.example.loginapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.UUID;

public class second extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Emergency_message");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

    public void Alert(View view) {
        ref.child(MainActivity.uniqueID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 {
                    String message = snapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                    String phone  = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                    System.out.println(message);
                     System.out.println(phone);
                     smsmini(phone , message);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(second.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


//
    });


    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query applesQuery = ref.child("Emergency_message").orderByChild("phone").equalTo(MainActivity.phone_number);
        applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }


                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(second.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


//
        });


                Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        startActivity(intent);

    }


    private void smsmini(String value, String value2) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(value, null, value2 , null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

SO here you can see (mainacitivity) only when i click the button(smsbutton) call out and phone_number  variable initialize so its is comparing with null and my app close .. SO please help i Cant make logic for it

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Emergency_message");
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(phone_number)) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , second.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            System.out.println(uniqueID);
                        }



                }
```

** LOG FILE OR SAY ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.loginapp, PID: 18604
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:256)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:167)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1027)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.isValidPathString(Validation.java:40)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(Validation.java:44)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.hasChild(DataSnapshot.java:80)
        at com.example.loginapp.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:59)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18604 SIG: 9
```

**LOGOUT OPTION**

```
public void logout(View view) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        finish();


        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query applesQuery = ref.child("Emergency_message").orderByChild("phone").equalTo(MainActivity.phone_number);
        applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }


                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(second.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


//
        });


                Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

**Alert OPTION** THIS function is used to retrive data from database(REALTIME) and sent the message so Can any1 help me to do more precisely ...

```
public void Alert(View view) {
        SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String preference_phoneNumber = defPref.getString("phone", "");
        ref.child(preference_phoneNumber).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 {
                     String message = snapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                     String phone  = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                     System.out.println(message);
                     System.out.println(phone);
                     smsmini(phone , message);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(second.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


//
    });


    }
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: no need of logcat only reason is its checking with null thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store user provided Phone Number through `Shared Preference` also while user updating data in `smsbutton` void.

   ```
    public void smsbutton(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    phone_number = editText.getText().toString();
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName4);
    String value2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    dataholder obj = new dataholder(phone_number, value2);


    myRef.child(uniqueID).setValue(obj);
    openAcitivity();

    //store
    if (phone_number != null) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("phone", phone_number);
        editor.putString("randomuid",uniqueID);
        editor.commit();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Data send ",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

   public void openAcitivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, second.class);

    startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```
2. Get value of all `phone` child of your `DatabaseReference` and compare with saved phone number by `Shared Preference` , if it match then ..

Use this updated method--

```
 private void checkexist() {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Emergency_message");
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                String phoneNumber_from_database = (String) ds.child("phone").getValue();
                Log.d("ZI",phoneNumber_from_database);

                SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                String preference_phoneNumber = defPref.getString("phone", "");

                if (phoneNumber_from_database.equals(preference_phoneNumber)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

**Update - Remove value**

Instead using `MainActivity.phone_number` in `logout` use saved phone number through `Shared Preference` .

```
    public void logout(View view) {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String preference_phoneNumber = defPref.getString("phone", "");
    Query applesQuery = ref.child("Emergency_message").orderByChild("phone").equalTo(preference_phoneNumber);
    applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            {
                for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }


            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(second.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


  //
    });


            Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    startActivity(intent);

}
```

**Update - `NullPointerException` while try to send sms**

1. Make sure you are using respective permission in manifest file .
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`
2. You are using `MainActivity.uniqueID` which is random , its not correct way in this case . Just store `uniqueID` with phone number through `Shared Preference` in `smsbutton` by `editor.putString("randomuid",uniqueID);` . I have added this line to your `smsbutton` void .
3. Retrieve the `uniqueID`  from Preference and use it as child to fetch data. And use `try..catch` exception to avoid `NullPointerException` , it caused by user deny permission or if database don't have such `message` child  .

So its your `Alert`

```
    public void Alert(View view) {

    SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String uniqueID = defPref.getString("randomuid", "");

    ref.child(uniqueID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            {
                try {
                    String message = snapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                    String phone  = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    System.out.println(phone);


                    smsmini(phone, message);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(second.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


 //
    });


   }
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the final update , hope this will help you

Comment: yess it works perfectly but please check my second acitivity i have also done a logout option where the data in that child delete but now(update ones ) is not deleting the data so how to do that please help me

Comment: like i am closing the app from recent and when i open the app again it successfully take me second page but if i click to logout its not deleting the user data from database

Comment: yess it excatly working bro Thanks a lot I love you brother can i find you somewhere in social media or anywhere else

Comment: Can you please check the alert option also its not working sometime sometime app crash                                                                                
                                                                                         
                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.loginapp.second$1.onDataChange(second.java:42)

Comment: sorry for delay , please check the update to fix `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thankss finally my project is done just need to add location there then over how can I thank you dont know...... Please give me your any contact want to talk personally

Comment: please check profile , facebook profile link added in website link .